# Symbolic Toolkit - Piecewise function gives NaN

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

So I have the following function:

```
psi(z,mu) = piecewise(mod(mu,2)==1, sin((mu+1)*z), mod(mu,2)==0, cos(mu*z)) ;
```

However this gives me psi(z,mu) = NaN for mu>2, and I am not sure why.

Comment: [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559382/52738) gave you a good workaround for this issue. You could also use it (and some trig) to avoid calling `piecewise` by defining your function like so: `psi(z,mu) = cos(mu*z+(mu-2*floor(mu/2))*(z-(pi/2)));`

Comment: Matlab's `sym/mod` unfortunately can't be used this way. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mod.html) is clear: "If `a` is a polynomial expression, then `mod(a,b)` finds the modulus for each coefficient."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a very odd issue that would appear to be a problem with using mod in the symbolic environment.

A fix that I found to work was to just replace mod with `mu-2*floor(mu/2)`, which is a definition of mod often used with languages that do not have the mod function.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Thought I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to call [MuPAD's modulo operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/mod.html) with [`feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html). In your case, you can create a new `mod` function:

```
syms z mu
mods(z,mu) = feval(symengine,'_mod',z,mu);
psi(z,mu) = piecewise(mods(mu,2)==1, sin((mu+1)*z), mods(mu,2)==0, cos(mu*z));
```

Now `psi(1,3)` will return `sin(4)`. If `mu` is not an integer, `NaN` is still returned.

(Note that [`psi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/psi.html) is also the name of a built-in Matlab function that you're shadowing: polygamma).